# Create Survey Form in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, survey

I want to create one survey form with the help of Angular Js and JSON.
In this survey form, I want to ask 4-5 questions to the user including text field, radio button, checkbox etc. When a user submits this form the result will display in graph format. So how can I do this? Give me a suggestion.

Comment: What part of the process do you have a question about? There's a lot that could go into that -- Angular forms and submission on the frontend, a backend receiving responses, a database to store survey data in, software to create a graph from the data.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as too broad. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

Comment: have you tired anything ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use surveyjs and embed survey into your website.

Here are multiple examples-
https://surveyjs.io/Examples/Library?id=questiontype-text&platform=jQuery&theme=modern#content-html